# how do you unenqueue a single item from sidekiq

Tags: sidekiq

Is there an a way to remove a single item (like this) from the enqueued "stack" of sidekiq:

```
irb(main):017:0> Sidekiq::Queue.all.first.first.methods
=> [:[], :delete, :args, :value, :klass, :item, :parse, :queue, :created_at, :jid, :latency, :display_class, :display_args, :enqueued_at, :to_json, :`, :methods, :singleton_methods, :protected_methods, :private_methods, :public_methods, :to_yaml, :to_yaml_properties, :blank?, :present?, :presence, :psych_to_yaml, :as_json, :acts_like?, :to_param, :to_query, :deep_dup, :duplicable?, :in?, :presence_in, :instance_values, :instance_variable_names, :with_options, :html_safe?, :is_haml?, :pretty_print, :pretty_print_cycle, :pretty_print_instance_variables, :pretty_print_inspect, :require_dependency, :unloadable, :require_or_load, :load_dependency, :try, :try!, :instance_of?, :public_send, :instance_variable_get, :instance_variable_set, :instance_variable_defined?, :remove_instance_variable, :kind_of?, :instance_variables, :tap, :method, :public_method, :singleton_method, :class_eval, :is_a?, :extend, :pretty_inspect, :define_singleton_method, :to_enum, :enum_for, :awesome_inspect, :awesome_print, :<=>, :===, :suppress_warnings, :=~, :!~, :eql?, :respond_to?, :freeze, :inspect, :display, :object_id, :send, :gem, :to_s, :ai, :nil?, :hash, :class, :singleton_class, :clone, :dup, :itself, :taint, :tainted?, :untaint, :untrust, :trust, :untrusted?, :frozen?, :!, :==, :!=, :__send__, :equal?, :instance_eval, :instance_exec, :__id__]
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it

```
Sidekiq::Queue.all.first.first.delete
```